# Standard deviation from sample data

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

Hi I am wondering how to calculate the standard deviation from sample data when you are just given the sum of $X^2$, the sum of $X$ and a value for $n$. Every formula I try gives me a error as it ends up with a negative root.
For example here is a question im stuck on: $n=90, \sum X^2 = 353.1916, \sum X= 177.9$ and then they got a result of $0.132$ for the standard deviation.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For future reference, formatting tips are [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

$$V(X) = E[X^2] - (E[X])^2$$
$E[X^2] = \frac{1}{n}\sum X^2$ and $E[X] = \frac{1}{n}\sum X$
So the variance is $$\frac{353.1916}{90}-\Big(\frac{177.9}{90}\Big)^2$$
and the sample standard deviation is the square root of the variance: 0.1309, slightly different from the claimed answer, which could be rounding issues.

Comment: Or from your failure to use $n-1$ in the denominator of the sample variance. // Using R as a calculator, code `sqrt((353.1916 - 177.9^2/90)/89)` returns
$0.1316533,$ which rounds to $0.132,$ without error.  // However, one must not round either term in the numerator, or actual rounding errors may arise. // (+1) for generally the right idea.

Comment: @BruceET Thank you for the correction.

Comment: Thanks guys that really helped me 